# When try to send dispatch mail from mail campaign , i received minus number of users received the mail campaign

Tags: sitecore-client, exm, campaigncreator

When try to put my email in notifications of mail campaign to receive dispatch mail with the number of users who received mail campaign I get an email number with a minus sign.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you see in Exm and in Eds logs?

Comment: nothing mentioned

Comment: The number of messages sent should be equal to `Total Sent - Bounced emails`. Can you see any bounced emails? Another reason could be due to deletion of some contact records that have been added to the recipient list before the email campaign was sent out